# Exception Handling in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

Recently I have been developing in Zend Framework. I came into a confusion during exception handling.

Can anybody let me know where is the best place to handle exception? Whether it is model or controller? It may be in terms of performance or usability or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to catch all kinds of exceptions, we better enable our model to throws exception. You can read this post also [link](http://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/12/make-your-zend-framework-error-controller-handle-php-errors/)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle exceptions in your controllers because sometimes the error messages of exceptions should be passed on to views. To avoid the dependency between models and views you should handle exceptions in your controllers.

Zend Framework all ready handles exceptions through the inbuilt errorController. You can enable it by placing the following line in your config file.

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0
```

Also, if you want to handle exceptions your self, rather then handling them at different places you can just handle them at one place. Something like below.

**Tell Zend Framework to not handle exceptions. Do this in your application.ini**

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 1
```

**Do following in your Bootstrap class.**

**Define a custom method to handle exceptions.**

```
public function __handleExceptions(Exception $e){
        //render a view with a simple error message for the user
        //and send an email with the error to admin
    }
```

Override the `_bootstrap()` and `run()` methods of `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` in your Bootstrap class and catch the exceptions thrown during the bootstrap process or while running the application and call your exception handler as shown below.

```
protected function _bootstrap($resource = null)
    {
        try {
            parent::_bootstrap($resource);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        try {
            parent::run();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }
```

Now all your exceptions will be handled from a single place.